# Create XML file in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fs

I am working in react js. Consuming API and getting response as JSON. Converting these JSON data into XML and trying to write file into client system. I use fs package for writing file. I am getting error.
**`TypeError: fs.appendFile is not a function`**
I also try to write plain text file not able to create same error coming.

Code

```
var buffer = Buffer.from?Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(jsonData)):new Buffer(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
var result = jsonxml(buffer,{escape:true});

fs.appendFile('mynewfile1.xml', result, function (err) {
  if (err){debugger; throw err;};
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```

I am using

```
Node- 10.13.0
Npm- 6.4.1
Fs-0.0.1-security
React- 16.8.6
```